# Break inheritance before creating new list with in same site

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Is there a way of breaking inheritance before creating new list/library so that there is no need to delete all security groups from permissions and create new(my site have lots lots of groups, so not able to delete all groups is not possible in single attempt.)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [SPList.BreakRoleInheritance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee550474.aspx)

```
SPList list = ... // list creation code
list.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
```

All permissions from the parent will be deleted. But the current user will be added with "Full Control".

Comment: How can i implement this to all kinds of lists/libraries/pages created?  Do i have to write code to all kind of lists?

Comment: Yes, you have to do it manually. How are the objects created, via code or via UI?

Comment: righr now everything is created through UI